# Change the JSON to a JSON array

Tags: .net, json, serialization, arrays

In my VB.net Web Api, I am using JsonWriter to build a Json Array then pass it to Client Side as a list(Of VerifyReturn) considering VerifyReturn is the name of a class.

```
  Public Class VerifyReturn
    Public Property Name as String
    Public Property AnotherName as String
  End Class
```

Here's my VB.net code:

```
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
  Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
  jsonWriter.WriteStartObject()

  jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Name")
  jsonWriter.WriteValue("Value")
  jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("AnotherName")
  jsonWriter.WriteValue("AnotherValue")

  jsonWriter.WriteEndObject()
  Dim ReturnJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of VerifyReturn))(sb.ToString)
```

I am getting this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EFramework.VerifyReturn]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

I am new and just learning JSON.

I would like to change the JSON to a JSON array.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON doesn't allow associative arrays, thus objects are used.

In JSON your example is

```js
{"Name":"Value","AnotherName":"AnotherValue"}
```

Assuming you want an array with each property as an object that would look like:

```js
[{"Name":"Value"},{"AnotherName","AnotherValue"}]
```

And your code would look like:

```vb
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
jsonWriter.WriteStartArray()

jsonWriter.WriteStartObject()
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Name")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("Value")
jsonWriter.WriteEndObject()

jsonWriter.WriteStartObject()
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("AnotherName")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("AnotherValue")
jsonWriter.WriteEndObject()

jsonWriter.WriteEndArray()

Dim ReturnJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of DifferentClass))(sb.ToString)
```

---

Alternatively, if you need a list of your your class, then only wrap an array around it:

```vb
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
jsonWriter.WriteStartArray()

jsonWriter.WriteStartObject()
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Name")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("Value")

jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("AnotherName")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("AnotherValue")
jsonWriter.WriteEndObject()

jsonWriter.WriteEndArray()

Dim ReturnJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of VerifyReturn))(sb.ToString)
```

This should result in:

```js
[{"Name":"Value", "AnotherName","AnotherValue"}]
```